# DialogFlow v2 Helper intents throw Reference Errors

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to use the Helper intents provided in the Actions on Google Library (for DialogFlow v2), without any luck so far. The code compiles perfectly fine, yet upon execution (both on mobile and the simulator), the invocation throws a Reference error. I have searched the Internet globe, bu no luck so far. Any suggestions?

My Code (based on https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#confirmation and nearly identical)

```
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow();

...

app.intent('program', conv => {
   if (somestatement) { 
     const parameters =  somedata;
     conv.contexts.set(contextVariable, 1, parameters);
     return conv.ask(new Confirmation('prompt!')); 
   }
});
```

The thrown Error:

```
ReferenceError: Confirmation is not defined
    at app.intent.conv (/user_code/index.js:161:25)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:146:23)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:22:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:18:12)
    at Function.handler (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:84:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:55:32)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:22:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:18:12)
```

I am also using the latest actions-on-google dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
     "actions-on-google": "^2.1.2",
     "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
     "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3",
     "sprintf-js": "^1.1.1"
}
```

I have even changed the new Confirmation() helper to any of the other helpers, with no luck. On the DialogFlow side, I have an intent as required by the same documentation link above.

Any help is much obliged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the `Confirmation` object, so replacing your first line with something like this should work:

```
const { dialogflow, Confirmation } = require('actions-on-google');
```

Comment: Damn. Worked! I have been searching for the documentation how to use it, but have I overlooked it? Do you know where to look for the reference? It doesn't say on the guide here https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#confirmation

Comment: Trust me - you haven't overlooked it.

Comment: So, to bother you again. I have been plowing for hours now to receive the result from this confirmation. As the documents indicate, I've made a Dialogflow Intent that should return the result to my fullfillment. But neither can I catch the response with the Intent name, nor with any variation of the Confirmation event name. It keeps resulting in a no-intent response. Any thoughts?

Comment: Several, but your best bet is to create a **new question on SO** and post as much information as you can, including screen shots of the intent you think should be getting the results, how you're handling that, and screen shots or any JSON of logs. If you know what is being sent back from your webhook, including that will help.